# Is "Big Resource" Just A Big Illegal Scam?

Tags: discussion, licensing

Is the site [http://vb.net.bigresource.com](http://vb.net.bigresource.com/asp-net-StreamReader-ReadLine-is-reading-every-other-line--JjO8ISTjM.html) violating SO's "cc with attribution required" licence? It appears to mirror SO posts without any attribution.

Comment: The fact that this is being reported in increasing frequency tells me that it is showing up in more searches. It was pervasive in PHP related searches for a while, then vanished from results, now back. What search engine gave it to you as a result?

Comment: @TimPost: It was [this Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=readline+again&aq=f&oq=readline+again&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j59l2j60l2.761j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=vb.net+streamreader+readline+twice&oq=vb.net+streamreader+readline+twice&gs_l=serp.12...3964.7051.1.7480.18.17.0.0.0.3.201.1595.12j4j1.17.0...0.0...1c.1.14.psy-ab.GKPzdGOlyvo&pbx=1&fp=1&biw=1440&bih=753&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&cad=b&sei=6v-lUeiWGsXm7AauvIGABQ). The true SO result sits just above the BR result, but _(continued)_

Comment: _(continued)_ I didn't know at the time that they were the _same_ result (indeed, there are cosmetic differences in the title, probably due to later edits on SO) and had opened the first few results in a handful of tabs simultaneously.

Comment: It mirrors everybody’s posts without attribution. When I’m googling things, it’s usually the case that it will show up in the top 10 (for, say, [Unix.SE]) if Stack Overflow didn’t.

Comment: Big Resource is just an aggregator; they just show search results from other sites :/